NSExtensionActivationRule for Safari
I have NSExtensionActivationRule in the ShareExtension as below:
SUBQUERY(
    extensionItems,
    $extensionItem,
    SUBQUERY(
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.plain-text"
    ).@count >= 1
).@count >= 1
OR 
SUBQUERY(
    extensionItems,
    $extensionItem,
    SUBQUERY(
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url"
        || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.content"
        || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.apple.webarchive"
    ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count
).@count >= 1
OR 
SUBQUERY(
    extensionItems,
    $extensionItem,
    SUBQUERY(
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image"
        || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.movie"
    ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count AND $extensionItem.attachments.@count <= 3
).@count == 1

I can see my app from Photo's share option, but I can't see it from Safari's share option. If I select either PDF or Web Archive from share Options, then I can see my app. What am I missing?

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with SharePoint. Did you store the photos in SharePoint?

It seems like it was iOS18.0.1 bug. After I updated to 18.1.1, this issue has gone.

Ok. Congratulations!
